# Netcat - how to get connection time?

Tags: ubuntu, netcat

I use simple code to test some service:

```
nc -v -w 2 google.com 80
Connection to google.com 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
```

It works pretty well, but I also need to have a connection time. Is it possible to get it by netcat? I can't find this in the manual :(

Answer (score 3):

If you use ncat (packaged with nmap) instead of netcat, you can get connection timing information like this:

```
ncat -v -z google.com 80
```

The output will appear something like this:

```
Ncat: Version 7.70 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to 172.217.15.78:80.
Ncat: 0 bytes sent, 0 bytes received in 0.35 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
echo "[$(date)] Connection to $SERVER $PORT port [tcp/http] $(nc -z $SERVER $PORT &> /dev/null && echo succeeded || echo failed)"
```

Example:

```
$ echo "[$(date)] Connection to google.com 80 port [tcp/http] $(nc -z google.com 80 &> /dev/null && echo succeeded || echo failed)"
[Mon Apr 10 12:40:31 UTC 2017] Connection to google.com 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded

$ echo "[$(date)] Connection to google.com 80 port [tcp/http] $(nc -z google2.com 80 &> /dev/null && echo succeeded || echo failed)"
[Mon Apr 10 12:40:20 UTC 2017] Connection to google.com 80 port [tcp/http] failed
```

Answer (score -2):

```
time nc -zw30 <host> <port>

// example:
$ time nc -zw30 google.com 443
Connection to google.com port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!

real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.003s
sys     0m0.006s
```

Reference: https://serverfault.com/questions/649532/what-is-the-best-way-to-measure-latency-via-a-telnet-to-port-test-preferably